# Coercing a vector to numeric mode in R

Tags: r, numeric, maximize

So, I have a set of data, and what I'm trying to do is find all the local maxima on the resulting curve. I read in a CSV file, which has x-values in the first column and y-values in the second, first step done, easy.

To find the maxima, I tried to use the `findpeaks()` function from the `pracma` database. However, each time I tried to run it, I got the same error:

```
Error: is.vector(x, mode = "numeric") is not TRUE
```

So, I first tried just converting this to a vector. Still got the same issue, however `is.vector(x, mode = "any")` was now returning true. I found some other help threads (which I can no longer find, so I can't share them, sorry!), and decided to try using `lapply` to coerce each entry in the new vector using `as.numeric`. Didn't work. Looked into `?as.numeric`, and it mentioned that `as.double` might be better suited. Didn't work. Now I'm at a loss and not sure what to do - current working code is shown below.

```
plot <- read_csv("AFGP60 UV-05-04-16.csv", 
               col_names = FALSE, na = "null", skip = 2,n_max = numrow)
diffplot <- c(plot[1:601,2])
diffplot <- lapply(diffplot,as.double)
findpeaks(diffplot)`
```

Comment: From your description, it's impossible to know what your data actually looks like. Use tools like `str()` and `dput()` to show your data.

Comment: You probably read it in as a string, and it was probably quoted in the CSV. The fix is to use`read_csv(..., col_types)` Please dump us the data as @RomanLuštrik asked. Also, don't tell us *"using `as.numeric` didn't work"*; show us the exact error warning (as well as the data).

Comment: I didn't want to share the data because of its size, and the fact that it's a part of my research. Was hoping I'd given enough information in my description of the data itself. However, I didn't know about the functions str() and dput() - dput() made me realise that the vector was getting stored in a list, so I simply added diffplot <- unlist(diffplot), and that did the trick!

As for `as.numeric` not working, there wasn't much of an error warning to show. As.numeric did its thing, and then I got the same error about `is.vector` returning false.

Answer (score 0):

Try `diffplot <- as.numeric(as.vector(plot[1:600, 2]))`.

The problem was that the data was read as character or as factor. The above code should change that. However, there are multiple issues with your code. First, `plot` is a base function used for plotting. Naming a variable with such a name is bad practice.

Second, the `diffplot` variable is a vector (first 600 rows from the second column), so there is no need to change each element separately with the `lapply` function.

Comment: Unfortunately didn't work - I figured out why, though. Turns out diffplot was being stored in a list, so is.vector returned false because each time it checked, it saw a list, and so coercion wasn't the problem. Thanks so much for offering your time to help - and I'll definitely remember the thing about lapply in future!